# How can I get computed property from methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

First of all, I'm using [this](https://github.com/PeachScript/vue-infinite-loading) module to make infinite loading in Vue.

To add elements every loading, I put json data from my API server to **data object**, and I save the arrays to the variables again after I splits the array into groups the size of '4'. but the thing is that It appends elements using method event handler which can't get any variable from computer property. I'm pretty new to Vue and I couldn't find any info about this. Here's code!

```
 export default {
  name: 'main',

  data: () => ({
    items: [],
    line: []
  }),

  async created () {
    this.items = await fetch('/videos').then(res => res.json())
  },

  computed: {
      columns: function() {
          return chunk(this.items, 4)
      }
  },

  methods: {
    onInfinite() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const temp = []
        const len = this.columns.length
        for (let i = len + 1; i <= len + 5; i++) {
          temp.push(this.columns[i])
          console.log(this.columns[i]) //It prints 'undefined'
        }

        this.list = this.list.concat(temp)
        this.$refs.myRefName.$emit('$InfiniteLoading:loaded')

      }, 700)
    },
  },
  components: {
    InfiniteLoading
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the code for `chunk`?

Comment: ime `chunk` takes an array and returns an array of arrays of each length `n`, the "chunks" so I assume thats whats happening here but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const len = this.columns.length // length of `columns` array
```

Next line:

```
for (let i = len + 1; i <= len + 5; i++) {
  ...this.columns[i]
```

You're trying to access indexes above array's length, which values are undefined obviously.

You should probably just loop through `columns` like this:

```
for (let column of columns) {
   for (let item of column) { // asuming column is Array(4)
      console.log(item)
```

It should work if your `columns` is an array of 'chunk' arrays with 4 elements in each.

Answer (score 0):

you this keyword to get computed method like this:

```
item.push(this.column[i]);
```